# Error in importing numpy shown by VS Code

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

Whenever I try :

```
import numpy as np
```

I get this error in my VS Code terminal :

```
   import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I already have numpy installed in my device...

Then thinking that the numpy installed must be in the wrong location I ran the command `pip install numpy` in the VS Code terminal, it got successfully installed but still the same error.
I expected I would be able to use it but that did not work as well.

Comment: try to change the python interpreter in VSCode. ctrl+shift+p then type "python select Interpreter", make sure it's using the same python version one as the terminal where you installed numpy

Comment: Tried all interpreters... Nothing worked... Please help

Answer (score 0):

Please check where you have installed your numpy library , if you are using python 3 then execute your code using below command

```
python3 <filename>.py
```

Comment: Did not worked...

Comment: Whats your python version?

Comment: Python 3.11.4  (Latest version)

Comment: Can you downgrade your python version to 3.9 and try it

Comment: how to downgrade in linux?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually caused by an incorrect Python interpreter.

You can use shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type **Python: Select Intepreter** to choose the interpreter where you installed the numpy package.

If you are just trying to debug quickly or just want the files to run, you can use command `pip install numpy` to reinstall without changing the interpreter in the current terminal.